# Phrase translation "Zeit nimmt alles"

Tags: meaning, translation

I need to know if

> "Zeit nimmt alles"

is a valid phrase, I think it translates to

> "Times take everything".

The context is for "Time takes everything" is more like "Time takes every pain away" (might be the dead of a close person, breakup, disappointment, etc.) but not saying pain in the phrase, how would it be translated to german?

Should it be "Die Zeit nimmt alles"?

Comment: What do you want to say with this expression? Actually it's hard to answer your question, so some more context is necessary. By now, your question is a simple proof-reading request which will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Is the english expression correct? I think it should either be "time take**s** everything" or "time**s** take everything".

Comment: Ok, so sorry if I didn't explain myself very well. I know it's not a German saying, I just want to translate the english phrase "Time takes everything" to German and I thought "Zeit nimmt alles" was the translation. If I'm mistaken with "Zeit nimmt alles", what should the translation be? Thanks a lot!

Comment: tbh I never heard either of both before. Where did you hear/read that? perhaps a little more context would help

Comment: Wordwise and grammatically, "Zeit nimmt alles" is a correct translation of "Time takes everything". But it could **still** be wrong because translations should reflect meanings and not just words. For that purpose, it is required to understand/know what the intended meaning of "Time takes everything" is. Is that an idiom or saying in English?

Comment: I mainly agree with @Min-SooPipefeet In German you would specify what is taken away by time and in these cases there would be better ways to word it, unless you want it to be ambivalent on purpose. The English phrasing confuses me just as the German one. So it's not necessarily *wrong*, it just depends on where you plan to use this phrase. It sounds awkward and stilted for everyday language. Nobody talks like that, but it might be used for poetry or such.

Comment: For "Time takes every pain away", there is the German saying "Zeit heilt alle Wunden" - as already mentioned in the answer - , literally translated: "Time heals all wounds".

Answer (score 6):

There is a German saying

> Zeit heilt alle Wunden.

literally translated: *"Time heals all wounds."*